# Aptana3 CSS Indentation

Tags: css, aptana, aptana3, autoformatting

So i've just switched to Aptana3. Works great, but for one thing.
In my preferences I can change how my indentation works in my files. I want them somewhat bigger (like 4 spaces). This works for all the file types I uses except for CSS. I uses an indentation of 2 spaces, which for me is too small. And the problem is, I can't change it.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Go to where you started (window -> preferences -> aptana studio -> formatter). Now select CSS, double click. Set "Tab policy" to spaces only, and choose how many spaces you want to indent. That's it.

Comment: Almost worked. But I discovered it is not because I have .scss files. Aptana has a way wit .css or .sass, but not with scss.

Comment: You should be able to add an editor association for scss files to use the CSS editor if it is not already present. General > Editors > File Associations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

On Apple you'll need to go to the preferences under the aptana studio 3 submenu.

Then go to aptana studio 3 > editors > sass and put it on the number you want.

Restart aptana and it should work. Sometimes It returned to the default value though. So if it resets, check again.